# How to read the all column names of an uploaded csv file

Tags: javascript, angular

In my project I am using ngx-file-drop and angular 5.2.

I want to get all the column names of an uploaded CSV file. How can I do that?

Comment: i want to read only column names not entire data @piotrszybicki

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using csvtojson library, then you could convert your data from the file to a json object.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#from-csv-file-to-json-array